# Android show a black screen instead white screen

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

I made app android and work fine with all devices, but when tested it with device (Android 4.1.2) it show me a black screen!

[Normal Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwc4Y.png)

[Black Screen(wrong show)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE5va.jpg)

onCreate Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ajouter_facture);

    btndate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateFacture);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    BundleNature = bundle.getString("Nature");
    Type = bundle.getString("Type");
    if (Type.equals("AddButton")){
        setTitle("Ajouter Facture");
        generateNumFacture();
    }
    if (Type.equals("OpenButton")){
        setTitle("Modifier Facture");
        getFacture();
        getLigneFacture();

    }

    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Sansation_Bold.ttf");

    left1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_text1);
    left1.setTypeface(type);
    left2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.left_text2);
    left2.setTypeface(type);
    right1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.montantTotal);
    right1.setTypeface(type);
    right2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.montantTotalFacture);
    right2.setTypeface(type);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_liste_lignefacture);

    lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
    adapter = new LigneFactureAdapter(this,ligneFactList);
    ligneFactList.clear();
    ligneComFact.clear();


    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDialogOnClick();

    et_NumFacture = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numFactureTV);
    et_NumCommande = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numCFactTV);
    et_CodeClient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeClientFactTV);
    et_MatriculeEmploye = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.matriculetEmployeFactTV);
    et_Etat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.etatPaiFactTV);
    et_Remise = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remiseFactTV);
    et_PourBoir = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pourBoirTF);
    tvMontant = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.montantTotalFacture);
    tvTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.montantTotal);
    btnAddLignFact = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAjouterLigneFacture);

    addLigneFactureCommande();
    getCodeClient();
    getMatriculeEmploye();
    populateEtatLiv();
    AddLigneFactureButton();
    updatePrixQuantite();
    updateRemisePourBoire();
    deleteLigneFacture();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <activity
        android:name="formulaires.AjouterFactureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ajouter_facture"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: please show code that displays the screen

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @SeddikFredj, paste the code for activity_ajouter_facture.xml here plz